# userFlow with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't get UserFlow to work for our AngularJS app.

The product runs on old AngularJS (1.8) and we love the concept of UserFlow , but the typical injection and init model runs in the core JS scope which AngularJS does not have access to... so, even after following the onboarding instructions, **every user that registers is appearing to UserFlow as the same {{userId}}**

We believe this is happening (UserFlow is not able to receive the user ID in `userflow.identify` as described [here](https://userflow.com/docs/dev/userflow-js-installation)) because the user ID is not known outside of the AngularJS digest. i.e. - the method was called in a place where angularJS is not taking effect, so the handlebars never get rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

**Got it fixed. An overview of how we fixed it is below:**

Simply split UserFlow's initialization into two distinct steps:

1. `userflow.init()` - this can be directly in your `index.html` or otherwise injected into the `<body>`
2. `userflow.identify()` - this has to be done within your AngularJS `controller`

.

**DETAILED STEPS---------------**

**1. `init()` normally, but use a build variable and don't `identify` yet**

In `index.html`, at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, add the following script:

```html
<!-- UserFlow -->
        <script ng-if="customization.features.userflow">
          !function(){var e="undefined"==typeof window?{}:window,t=e.userflow;if(!t){var r="https://js.userflow.com/";t=e.userflow={_stubbed:!0};var n=e.USERFLOWJS_QUEUE=e.USERFLOWJS_QUEUE||[],o=function(e){t[e]=function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);i(),n.push([e,null,t])}},s=function(e){t[e]=function(){var t,r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);i();var o=new Promise((function(e,r){t={resolve:e,reject:r}}));return n.push([e,t,r]),o}},a=function(e,r){t[e]=function(){return r}},u=!1,i=function(){if(!u){u=!0;var t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0;var n=e.USERFLOWJS_ENV_VARS||{};"es2020"===(n.USERFLOWJS_BROWSER_TARGET||function(e){for(var t=[[/Edg\//,/Edg\/(\d+)/,80],[/OPR\//,/OPR\/(\d+)/,67],[/Chrome\//,/Chrome\/(\d+)/,80],[/Safari\//,/Version\/(\d+)/,14],[/Firefox\//,/Firefox\/(\d+)/,74]],r=0;r<t.length;r++){var n=t[r],o=n[0],s=n[1],a=n[2];if(e.match(o)){var u=e.match(new RegExp(s));if(u&&parseInt(u[1],10)>=a)return"es2020";break}}return"legacy"}(navigator.userAgent))?(t.type="module",t.src=n.USERFLOWJS_ES2020_URL||r+"es2020/userflow.js"):t.src=n.USERFLOWJS_LEGACY_URL||r+"legacy/userflow.js",t.onerror=function(){u=!1,console.error("Could not load Userflow.js")},document.head.appendChild(t)}};o("_setTargetEnv"),o("closeResourceCenter"),o("init"),o("off"),o("on"),o("prepareAudio"),o("registerCustomInput"),o("remount"),o("reset"),o("setCustomInputSelector"),o("setCustomNavigate"),o("setCustomScrollIntoView"),o("setInferenceAttributeFilter"),o("setInferenceAttributeNames"),o("setInferenceClassNameFilter"),o("setResourceCenterLauncherHidden"),o("setScrollPadding"),o("setShadowDomEnabled"),o("setPageTrackingDisabled"),o("setUrlFilter"),o("openResourceCenter"),o("toggleResourceCenter"),s("endAll"),s("endAllFlows"),s("endChecklist"),s("group"),s("identify"),s("identifyAnonymous"),s("start"),s("startFlow"),s("startWalk"),s("track"),s("updateGroup"),s("updateUser"),a("getResourceCenterState",null),a("isIdentified",!1)}}();
          userflow.init('@@grunt_userflow')
        </script>
```

Since we use Grunt as a build tool (which I don't recommend, but you can replicate the same pattern with different technologies), we put the environment-specific token, `@@grunt_userflow`, into our build script which replaces the individual token to match the respective environment.

You'll notice here we're not calling `userflow.identify()` yet...

**2. Execute the UserFlow `identify()` directly within the controller**

When the user first logs in, now you need to execute the `userflow.identify()` function and pass in the right IDs. Personally, I like putting AngularJS-agnostic functions like this outside of the controller and then inherit them in:

```js
const startUserFlow = function(userId, login) {
  userflow.identify(userId, {
    email: login
  });
};
```

And, now calling that function from within AJS:

```js
$scope.processCredentials($scope.username, response.data.access_token).then(function (result) {
    trackEvent('signIn', $rootScope.userProfile.id);
    startUserFlow($rootScope.userProfile.id, $scope.username);
```

**3. Finally, to reinitialize your `Content`, use `ng-click=()` on any HTML  you'd like**

That's right - since we're scoping it in and doing this the AngularJS way, use ng-click like any other function and bind it directly. Example below.

```js
$scope.launchUserFlowChecklist = function () {
    userflow.start('[insert content ID here]');
};
```

I hope this helps! Cheers.